# leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter cannot load custom tiles because of CORS error

Tags: leaflet, tiles

If I try to make screenshots with my custom tiles, I am getting CORS errors. If I use mapbox or openstreet map tiles, I don't have any issues. I don't get any errors if custom tiles are used in Leaflet map, they are fetching with http 200 status.

[image]

When I make a screenshot, it looks like this:

[image]

and I am getting CORS errors when screenshot is generating:

```
Access to image at 'https://customTilesPlaceholder.com/tiles/orthophoto_tiles/21/608480/1304017.png' from origin 'https://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is how I add my custom tiles to the leaflet. The `drone` tileLayer doesn't appear in screenshots.

```
const openStreetMap = tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 26,
    maxNativeZoom: 18,
  })
  let satellite = {} as TileLayer
  if (import.meta.env.VITE_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) {
    satellite = tileLayer(
      `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${
        import.meta.env.VITE_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }`,
      { maxZoom: 26, maxNativeZoom: 22 }
    )
  }
  const customerTag = selectedUser?.value ? selectedUser.value : userData?.customerTag
  let overlayMaps: Record<string, TileLayer> = {}
  if (tileDirectories?.directories && tileDirectories?.config) {
    const orderedDirectories = orderDirectories(tileDirectories.directories, tileDirectories.config)
    if (import.meta.env.VITE_CUSTOM_MAP_TILES_URL && customerTag) {
      overlayMaps = orderedDirectories.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        let layer = {} as Layer
        layer = tileLayer(`${import.meta.env.VITE_CUSTOM_MAP_TILES_URL}${customerTag}/${curr}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, {
          minZoom: 11,
          maxZoom: 26,
          maxNativeZoom: 21,
          opacity: 1.0,
          tms: true,
        })
        return {
          ...acc,
          [curr]: layer,
        }
      }, {})
    }
  }
  let drone = {} as TileLayer
  if (import.meta.env.VITE_CUSTOM_MAP_TILES_URL) {
    drone = tileLayer(`${import.meta.env.VITE_CUSTOM_MAP_TILES_URL}orthophoto_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, {
      minZoom: 11,
      maxZoom: 26,
      maxNativeZoom: 21,
      opacity: 1.0,
      tms: true,
    })
  }
  const baseMaps = {
    OpenStreetMap: openStreetMap,
    Satellite: satellite,
  }
  overlayMaps = {
    Drone: drone,
    ...overlayMaps,
  }
  Object.values(baseMaps).forEach((layer) => {
    layer.addTo(context.map)
  })
  Object.values(overlayMaps).forEach((layer) => {
    layer.addTo(context.map)
  })
  control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(context.map)
```

This is the way how I take screenshots:

```
import { simpleMapScreenshoter } from 'lealfet;

const mapScreenshoter = simpleMapScreenshoter({
        hidden: true,
        hideElementsWithSelectors: ['.leaflet-control-container'],
        cropImageByInnerWH: true,
      }).addTo(context.map)

      mapScreenshoter
        .takeScreen('image', {
          mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
        })
        .then((base64Img) => {
          if (base64Img) {
            saveAs(base64Img, 'screen.png')
            // onTakeScreenshot?.(base64Img as unknown as string)
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          alert(e.toString())
        })
```

Do you have any idea why [leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter) is throwing CORS errors for fetching custom tiles?

I tried to use [crossorigin](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-crossorigin) option for `tileLayer` with empty string or `true` value, but with this settings my custom tiles are not loading at all.

This is cors settings in Node.js server that is hosting map tiles:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [/localhost:\d{4}$/, /domain\.placeholder\.ai$/, /domain\.placeholder\.ai$/],
    maxAge: 86400, // NOTICE: 1 day
    credentials: true,
  })
)
```

Comment: @TomazicM it is npm library [leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter)

Comment: Where are custom tiles served from? Local server, like `localhost`? Please edit your question with more info.

Comment: @TomazicM I just edited my question. I found out that while screenshot is generating, I am getting CORS errors. I don't understand why, because tiles in my Leaflet map are loading with http 200 status without any errors.

Comment: You are getting CORS errors because screen shooter plugin manipulates canvas where layer tiles are drawn. Obviously your server CORS settings do not allow that. When I tried it with local IIS server, I had no problems with CORS. Since I'm not familiar with that, can't help you any further.

Comment: Thank for checking! I just found the issue and solution. I needed to add `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` in nginx for fetching custom tiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` in nginx for custom tiles routes